# How can I create a matrix (sparse) from a list of 1 column data-frame by matching the row names

Tags: r

So I used an lapply statement to read and process 30 csv file; this creates a list of 1 column numeric data-frames with row names. I want to create a numerical matrix from this list of data-frames where the rows is the union of all the row.names() of the data-frames. The columns are the data frames (thus, will have 30 columns) and if that column doesn't match a row name, the value in the matrix will just be 0.

Here's code that works well with two data frames in that list, so that you can get the logic.

```
merge_dataframes <- function(df1, df2) {
  merge(df1, df2, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
}

combined_df <- Reduce(merge_dataframes, processed_files)

combined_df[is.na(combined_df)] <- 0
```

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please ... ?